# how to play video as popup and make background disable and fade out with bootstrap in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Currently, I am able to view the video on a page itself which I can view as full screen also.
I done this with jquery UI and bootstrap class

```
<div class="videoUiWrapper thumbnail">
```

I want to play video in webpage, but when I will click on play button, video should play as popup and webpage should be disabled and fade out.

How can I do this with bootstrap?

or with anything else.

I am developing website in asp.net c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for in bootstrap is "Modal". Have a look at this
[link for more information](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Personally I like to use this: [Bootstrap 3 Lightbox](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#single-youtube)